# How can I reduce the below code? I do not want to put the 'for loop' and want to accept input as a list of integers

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, list, math

I am trying to get a way of avoiding a 'for loop' and want to accept the input in an array of integers from the user and then work on it.

```
x = input().split(' ')
a = []
for i in x:
    a.append(i)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're simply copying all items in `x` to `a`, you might as well assign what you assign to `x` directly to `a` instead:

```
a = input().split(' ')
```

If you want each item in a list to be converted to an integer, you can map the items to the `int` constructor:

```
a = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
x=[temp for temp in input().split()]

print(x) // should print list of input elements
```

If you don’t want to use for you can use map

```
x=list(map(str, input().split()))
```

and if the you have integers separated by space you can do this:

```
x=[int(temp) for temp in input().split()]
```

Using map

```
x=list(map(int, input().split()))
```